# Google Script to execute IF Statement in a loop for date value

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script to automate a daily copy+paste (as value) function. I've worked through it piece-by-piece and my final issue is the looped if-statement that looks at the date relative to today's date.

You can see that in column B is my 'Date' column and in row 1 column AN I entered a today() function.

Essentially, everyday I copy and paste (as value) any rows (columns I - AM) that match 'today's' date, highlight them grey and then hide the rows. Once I can set up the if-statement for the loop to recognize the correct rows, I can set a daily trigger in the morning to run the function.

The code is below - any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
function dailyUpdate() 
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Copy of Results');
  var dateValues = sht.getRange(2,2,1231).getValues();
  for (r=1; r<1232; r++)
    var todayValue = sht.getRange(1,39).getValue();
    var dateValues = sht.getRange(r,2).getValues();
    if(dateValues == todayValue)
    {
      var source = sht.getRange(r,9,1,31);
      source.copyTo(sht.getRange(r,9,1,31), {contentsOnly: true});
      sht.hideRow(source)
      source.setBackground("grey");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have the same source and destination in "copyTo"... What is the sense? In the line "var dateValues = sht.getRange(r,2).getValues();" you have a single cell reference. May be you want "getValue" instead of "getValues"?

Comment: Adjusted for the single cell reference, however I'm copying to the same place as the source as it copying-to as "true" or 'values only.' This is to remove the in-place formulas and only have the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing `sht.getRange(1,39).getValue()` to `sht.getRange(r,2).getValues()`. `getValue()` returns a single value, where as `getValues()` returns a 2D array.
And since you're using formula in your sheet try `getDisplayValue()` instead of `getValues()`.

Try something like this:

```
function dailyUpdate()  {
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Copy of Results');
  var todayValue = sht.getRange(1,39).getDisplayValue();
  for (r=1; r<1232; r++) {
    var dateValue = sht.getRange(r,2).getDisplayValue();
    if(dateValue == todayValue) {
      var source = sht.getRange(r,9,1,31);
      source.copyTo(sht.getRange(r,9,1,31), {contentsOnly: true});
      sht.hideRow(source)
      source.setBackground("grey");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great catch - for some reason still not executing properly however. For what it's worth, the function now takes a couple of minutes to run, so I'm assuming that it is cycling through the necessary rows. Any other troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Sorry - Now only seeing your text, Great! You made it work! what was off ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delayed response - it was my own formatting! Your answer was spot on.